# When should Water Baptism be done on a candidate?

Tags: biblical-basis, baptism

Could you please give me any biblical supports as to when should water baptism be done to a candidate (assuming the candidate has already met the so called "requirements" before being baptized, such as repentance of all sins (past and present); acceptance of the Messiah as Personal Master and Savior; faith on the importance of our Savior's dying on the cross)?

When should the water baptism be done? Should it be on or during a biblical feast, such as Pesach, Shavout or Sukkot? For example, in Acts 2, Peter and the disciples had baptized 3000 believers during the Pentecost. On the water baptism of our Messiah by John, the Scripture is silent on when it was done; it could not be during or before any feast because after His baptism the Ruach Ha Khadosh brought Him to wilderness to be tempted for 40 days. In Acts 10:47-48, concerning the conversion of the centurion, his family and friends, Peter baptized them but again the Scripture is silent on when was it held.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. Because you are asking for research, this is a good question. Devoid of that request, some might be tempted to call it a "truth question," meaning one where somebody is looking for the definitively "right" answer, as opposed to one which states the predominant belief amongst a particular group.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's right after the potluck and right before the softball game during the annual church picnic. Isn't that in your copy of the scriptures?

Comment: As a Canadian, I'd suggest the answer "in summer".

Answer (score 1):

The scriptures never tell us on which occasion the baptism should be performed.

One thing for sure is that Baptism was done immediately after the candidate accepted Jesus Christ.

Some examples:

1. The first believers on the Pentecost day were Baptized that day itself.

   > Acts 2:41 (NIV) Those who accepted his message were baptized, and
   >   about three thousand were added to their number that day.
2. The Ethiopian eunuch took baptism shortly after accepting Jesus Christ. (Acts 8:26-40)

   > 36 As they traveled along the road, they came to some water and the
   >   eunuch said, “Look, here is water. What can stand in the way of my
   >   being baptized?”
3. The Jailer and his household took Baptism immediately the same night he accepted Jesus. (Acts 16:16-40)

   > 33 At that hour of the night the jailer took them and washed their
   >   wounds; then immediately he and all his household were baptized.
4. Cornelius the centurion and every one present in his house took baptism right after Peter preached to them. (Acts 10)

   > 44 While Peter was still speaking these words, the Holy Spirit came on
   >   all who heard the message.47 “Surely no one can stand in the way of
   >   their being baptized with water. They have received the Holy Spirit
   >   just as we have.”

There are more references but I believe this is sufficient.